# What is the best appraoch to take a copy of 3 related tables before doing modification to them

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

I have the following case:-

1. we have around 50 JSON files which contain data about items inside **AZURE** SQL server (mainly 3 Tables which have FK to each other)/
2. now what i am planning to do is as follow:-

- Run the first JSON extract >> check that all the items inside the JOSN were extracted correctly.
- But before starting the next JSON extract >> i want to take a copy of all the items inside the 3 tables. so in-case the second iteration failed , i do not have to start from the beginning again. in this case if N iteration failed, i will check why the N iteration failed >> fix it on the JSON files >> clear the 3 tables >> restore the tables copies after running the N-1 iteration>> re-run the N iteration again.

So can anyone advice what is the best way to take a copy of the 3 tables >> so it will allow me to restore the tables and keep their original ids and everything to be the same?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know about database transactions? If not, time for you to do some learning. If so, clarify in your Question why a simple transaction rollback cannot accomplish your goal.

Comment: A transaction wrapping your process is the obvious solution. Alternatively you could create a database snapshot.

Comment: @Stu i am using Power Automate to read the JSON and update the database.. so i can not use transaction.. can i do a snapshot for the 3 tables only, or i have to do it for the whole database (all tables, Stored procedures 7 views)?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes i know but i am using Power Automate flow to do the extraction and updating the database,,, so we can not use translocation inside Power autoamte

Comment: I'm referring to a *database snapshot* which creates a point-in-time representation of your database; snapshots only store changes to objects; if you modify a table after the snapshot is created the original version can be queried from the snapshot.

Comment: @Stu ok got your point.. so you mean before start a new iteration of extraction, i take a database snapshot >> run the new extraction >> if it fails, then i can replace the current database with the one found in the snapshot?

Comment: @johnGu kind of; you wouldn't replace the entire database, you'd simply restore the data in your tables from the snapshot. If you are the only user of the database (?) then you may as well take  normal copy-only backup and restore it if necessary.

Comment: @stu i do not think backup and restore will work, as we will delete all the records inside the 3 tables and then restore them,, so will this preserve the original ids and FKs between the tables?

Comment: Yes, it preserves all changes. [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and experiment.

Comment: @Stu i know that snapshot will preserve the ids .. i am talking about the backup/restore

Comment: @Stu i think snapshot is the way to go... but can you please explain what do you mean by `snapshots only store changes to objects; ` ? now if i take snapshots after each iteration will the last snapshot contain all the latest data? or it will only contain the data that has changed from the previous snapshot?

Comment: @Stu also iam using SQL Azure which seems doe snot support snapshots...

Comment: Indeed it does not, that's some additional cruicial info. If it's a fully managed instance then functionality such as this is not (and cannot be) supported since it requires access and control over the server and filesystem - you don't have this in Azure as it's managed for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to copy data into a new table is:

```
select  *
into table01_copy
    from table01

select  *
into table02_copy
    from table02

select  *
into table03_copy
    from table03
```

But, as was suggested in comments to your question, probably, transaction is better solution in your case.